# Unable to resize collection view cell based on label

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view which divides the screen in 2 equal parts.
The image is as shown below[image]

The flow layout is applied is as follows:

```
 if let layout = alllistcollview?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
                    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 20
                    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
                    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 40, right: 10)
                    let size = CGSize(width:(alllistcollview!.bounds.width-30)/2, height: 220)
                    layout.itemSize = size
        }
  
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {


        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 40, right: 10)
    }
```

The two labels below the image is dyanamic.The constraints applied for them are top,leading,trailing and height which is greater than value.
Now when the label height is greater than,then it is touching the collection view cell border.
How to resize the content within the collection view cell height.

Have also mentioned sizeforitem.The code is given below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
           // print(#function)
            let padding: CGFloat =  30
            let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding
        
       
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        label.text = self.searchDataModel!.data[self.searchDataModel!.data.count - 1 - indexPath.item].listingPrice
        label.sizeToFit()
        
        let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        label1.text = self.searchDataModel!.data[self.searchDataModel!.data.count - 1 - indexPath.item].listingTitle
        label1.sizeToFit()
                
        return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: 166 + label.frame.height + label1.frame.height)
        }
```

how to fix the contents within the collection view height?

Comment: Is your problem related to the `UILabel`s or the `UIImageView`s? From the screenshots looks like you should set your `UIImageView` content mode to `scaleAspectFill`.

Comment: You have marked the images. labels seem fine in the attached screen shot, can you revise the attached screen shot or update you question.